# merge multiple regex into one which could "catch them all"

Tags: python, regex

i have this specific problem where i have to find some regex to
match packages from our deployment system. So right now i have some
odd construct like this:

```
def myPkgs():
  txt = sys.argv # self.myPKG
                txt.pop(0)
                pkg_dict = {"Package" : "", "Version" : ""}
                pkg_list = []

                for i in txt:
                        re0= "^([a-zA-Z,0-9]*)(-|.)([0-9]*[.|-][0-9]*[.|-][0-9])([.][noarch]*)"
                        re1 = "^([a-z]*)(-|.)([a-zA-Z,0-9]*)(-|.)([0-9]*[0-9].....??)(-|.)([A-Z,0-9]*)([.][noarch]*)"
                        re2 = "^([a-z]*)(-|.)([a-zA-Z,0-9]*)(-|.)([0-9]*[0-9].....??[-|.][A-Z,0-9]*)"
                        rg0 = re.compile(re0)
                        rg1 = re.compile(re1)
                        rg2 = re.compile(re2)
                        m = rg0.search(i)
                        n = rg1.search(i)
                        o = rg2.search(i)

                        if m:
                                pkg_dict["Package"] = str(m.group(1))
                                pkg_dict["Version"] = str(m.group(3))

                                pkg_list.append(pkg_dict)
                        elif not m:
                                if n:
                                        pkg_dict["Package"] = str(n.group(1) +n.group(2)+ n.group(3))
                                        pkg_dict["Version"] = str(n.group(5) +n.group(6)+n.group(7))
                                        pkg_list.append(pkg_dict)
                                elif not n:
                                        if o:
                                                pkg_dict["Package"] = str(o.group(1) + o.group(2) + o.group(3))
                                                pkg_dict["Version"] = str(o.group(5))
                                                pkg_list.append(pkg_dict)
                                        else:
                                                print "No Packet named: %s found" % i
                                else:
                                        print "No Packet named: %s found" % i
                        else:
                                print "No Packet named: %s found" % i
                        yield pkg_list
```

but my problem is i still cant pull out exactly the package names and
version numbers. Is there a way to 'merge' the three regex patterns into 
one big regex which could 'catch them all' . The Packagenames to match against
can look some thing like this:

```
sqlldr-11.2.0.3.0-1.noarch
testbench-2.3-RC3.noarch
tomcat7-34-M1.noarch
uc4-jmx-agent-9.00A124.431-5.x86_64
uc4-jmx-monitoring-1.0-RC1.noarch
uc4-jmx-monitoring-1.0-RC2.noarch
uc4-server-9.00A220_241-2.x86_64
nexus-2.6.0-RC3.noarch
oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64
oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64
oracle-perl-11.2-RC1.noarch
perl-Crypt-Blowfish_PP-1.12-1:1.noarch
perl-jmx4perl-1.07-1:1.noarch
perl-Test-HTTP-Server-Simple-0.11-1:1.noarch
```

this list should be splitted into something like this:

thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Okay the package list is maybe some how missleading. Dont look at the noarch/x86_64 parts the thing i have to do (how the script finally has to work like. On the CLI the user gives a package name like "perl-jmx4perl-1.07-1:1.noarch" and then what i want the regex to do is to split the cli arg into "Package" and "Version" then the funktion iterates first over all packgaes to match the name. After that the function should iterate over the version numbers to find the exact version match. Or am i thinking to complicated? Please tell me.

Kind regards

**Edit**

```
sqlldr-11.2.0.3.0-1.noarch
testbench-2.3-RC3.noarch
tomcat7-34-M1.noarch
uc4-jmx-agent-9.00A124.431-5.x86_64
uc4-jmx-monitoring-1.0-RC1.noarch
uc4-jmx-monitoring-1.0-RC2.noarch
uc4-server-9.00A220_241-2.x86_64
nexus-2.6.0-RC3.noarch
oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64
oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64
oracle-perl-11.2-RC1.noarch
perl-Crypt-Blowfish_PP-1.12-1:1.noarch
perl-jmx4perl-1.07-1:1.noarch
perl-Test-HTTP-Server-Simple-0.11-1:1.noarch
```

should turn into something like:

```
[{'Version': '11.2.0', 'Package': 'sqlldr'}]
[{'Version': '2.3-RC3', 'Package': 'testbench'}]
[{'Version': '7-34-M1', 'Package': 'tomca'}]
[{'Version': '4-jmx-', 'Package': 'u'}]
[{'Version': '4-jmx-', 'Package': 'u'}]
[{'Version': '4-jmx-', 'Package': 'u'}]
```

but as you can see some important parts get parsed away. because i cant use a sting like '4-jmx-' for matching 
against the package repository. Or like 'tomca' which should be 'tomcat' so is there a way to match them all?
Or is this to tricky to bring a regex to work? Because the packge version (placement inside of the package name string) 
differ from package name to another. Does this clarify the isse better? And also i am asking myself if it would
be easier to make something like fuzzy matching... like not to find the exact match but either to take the string 
and make a selection and let the user decide which is the correct package? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well just to add, words are not allowed inside of a character class `[]`, I'm referring to where you have `[noarch]`

Comment: hmm okay, this is probably because i am really a newb when it comes to regex

Comment: Could you indicate how the package list should be separated into its package name and its version?

Comment: i would append the names into a key,value list with Package and Version for example: pkg_dict = {"Package" : "oracle-perl", "Version" : "11.2-RC1"} . I think if i can make the reges to split the names/version into these two parts the key,vaule list makes the whole thing more manageable.

Comment: Could you put @Jerry when you reply to me? Otherwise, I don't get any notification ^^; Okay, for this one, but could you update your question with the package name and version for each one? Just so we're virtually sure what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Dear @Jerry i made some adjustments to the post. I have posted the output from the skript as it is right now. I am not really shure if these are the adjustments you meant. :) if could you please kindly tell me more specific what you mean with 'update your question with the package name and version for each one' ?

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was asking for, but I don't think it's that clear to me. Could you maybe come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46067/tcl) and discuss about it?

Comment: @Jerry shure i will meet you there, but could you give me some time? Because i am really tiered, only slept 2 hours last night and i have to take a nap. After that i will join the room.. But only if you dont mind if i take a nap :)

Comment: @Jerry hey ther, i am sorry i missed your invitation yesterday. Only because i sleept through the rest of the day. I hope your invitation is still in effekt. I would like to discuss about the issue with you.

Comment: @PolymathMonkey Yep, the chatroom is open (and shouldn't be closed too soon!)

Comment: @Jerry, im in the chatroom. But nobody

Comment: @Jerry hey there :) , i attempted to run the regex against the packages. But i am not shure if they are correct. Because in the editor [http://regex101.com/r/gL3mG8] they look great (but some how the regextype dropdown says "pcre (php)" ) but if i am trying to make them work my interpreter says: "raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern". I think there is some issue with the expression?

Comment: @PolymathMonkey Oh yea, I'm not entirely used to Python named captures. The `(?' ... '` parts should be `(?P< ... >` instead

Comment: @Jerry hey look like the regex works nearly perfect, except for some special cases.... where the package name is like nagios-plugins-4blafoo-0.0-34 . But this seems to be the only special case for the pattern. So i would say the pattern works great ! :)

Comment: hmm okay one thing i have noted with the pattern is that some package names got the first letter cut off.. is there something i can do about that like: jboss6-batch-apps-patch with version: 14.1-RC5.1 and
boss6-patch with version: 14.1-RC5 is there some adjustment i can do about that?

Comment: @PolymathMonkey what is the original package name for the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?P<Package>.*?)-(?P<Version>\d.*?)\.(?:noarch|x86_64)$
```

The description:

```
^                   # Match the start of the string
(?P<Package>.*?)    # Match any number of characters and store them in 'Package' until...
-                   # a dash which is followed by...
(?P<Version>\d.*?)  # a digit, followed by any number of characters and store them in 'Version' until...
\.                  # a literal dot, then
(?:noarch|x86_64)   # noarch or x86_64
$                   # Match the end of the string
```

Here's an example with one package:

```
>>> pack = "oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64"
>>> reg = re.compile(r"^(?P<package>.*?)-(?P<version>\d.*?)\.(?:noarch|x86_64)$")
>>> m = reg.match(pack)
>>> m.groupdict()
{'package': 'oracle-instantclient11.2-basic', 'version': '11.2.0.3.0-1'}
```

In your code, I believe it could be something like this:

```
def myPkgs():
    txt = sys.argv # self.myPKG
    reg = re.compile(r"^(?P<Package>.*?)-(?P<Version>\d.*?)\.(?:noarch|x86_64)$")

    pkg_list = []

    for i in txt:
        m = reg.match(i)
        if m:
            pkg_dict = m.groupdict()
            pkg_list.append(pkg_dict)
        else:
            print "No Packet named: %s found" % i

        yield pkg_list
```

For the package in your comment, this regex might solve it, but I don't know about the other packages, if they would break on it:

```
^(?P<package>.*?)-(?P<version>\d+\b.*?)\.(?:noarch|x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this
i have tested all them and worked

since all Packagenames ends with ".noarch" or ".x86_64" it will catch them all

```
/(\w+[-\.][a-z]?\S+(?:\.noarch)?(?:\..x86_64)?)/
```